# Search Query Using Parse

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, windows-phone-7, parse-platform

I was querying parse Databse with about 1000 Users where I have to loop through every name to find some of them. Here is my query code,

```
 int count = arrPeopleName.count;
    for (int i =0; i<count; i++) {
         PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

        [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:[arrPeopleName objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


        NSLog(@"USERS %@",objects);  }];
```

Here People name array is static array with some names. So I guess the **for loop + RegEx Query**, is very costly Here and less efficient but I don't find suitable query , that is, Finding Matching Names. So if I just have **JOH** in array I should still get **JOHN,JOHNSON** etc.

So any good ideas for this. I was thinking of some Bulk Query here? If you could suggest me better solution it will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in the query:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" containedIn:arrPeopleName];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"USERS %@",objects);  
}];
```

This will return all users with a username that matches any username stored in arrPeopleName.

**UPDATE**

It seems to me you have two options, since Parse does not have API support for partial matching.

1. One option, which was suggested by Hector over at Parse, is to use a beforeSave cloud code hook where you split your info into tokens to store as array in another field. This seems to be kind of a hacky workaround, but I guess it could work. It would mean that when you store "johnson" as a username, the beforeSave function will split this into tokens like "jo", "joh", "john", "johns", "johnso", "ohn", "son" etc, and store these in an array. You can later compare your search string to values in this array (stored in another field in the Parse table). I guess this could work, but it does seem a bit too hacky for my taste.
2. Another option is to solve it entirely on the client side. The regex query is, as you said, not efficient and does not scale well on larger datasets. You could do the matching client side, with some caching as well.

Both these methods are explained in this forum post over at Parse:
https://parse.com/questions/partial-match-for-query

Seems you have to pick one of two bad alternatives. Sorry I can't be of more help. I would be interested in hearing what you end up with!

Comment: true; but will match exact same values from array. This won't be use as Regular expression to match only some part of the string from the array with whole DB.!! This is what I mentioned that, JOH in array I should still get JOHN,JOHNSON etc. It will be really helpful if you solve my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question well enough. Will update my answer.

Comment: Will wait for your expert answer, Thanks a lot Marius.

Comment: Unfortunately, Parse does not directly support partial matches against array values. I guess you could solve this with cloud code. I will have to chew on this a while longer. Promise to get back to you!

Comment: Ok Man, Thanks for your help. I would really wait for your answer and would definitely use it.

Comment: Marius Falkenberg Waldal, is there something relevant to cloud code with this??

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this, @Vish?

Comment: No Marius! Please help!

Comment: Have you tried containsString constraint of PFQuery?

Comment: Yes, but thats too expensive. For 10000 records it will be quite in efficient as parse says not to use them for large data! Is there anything in Cloud code where I can write down any logic that would return me some good results efficiently.!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions other what I have already answered. Good luck, though :-/